# Why is this function non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Why does SQL Server think this function is non-deterministic?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Util].[BuildStreetFullName]
(
    @StreetNumber VARCHAR(20),
    @StreetDir VARCHAR(2),
    @StreetName VARCHAR(50) ,
    @StreetType VARCHAR(4) ,
    @StreetPostDir VARCHAR(2) 
)
RETURNS VarChar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @StreetNumber   = NULLIF( Util.Trim(@StreetNumber   ), '');
    SET @StreetDir      = NULLIF( Util.Trim(@StreetDir      ), '');
    SET @StreetName     = NULLIF( Util.Trim(@StreetName     ), '');
    SET @StreetType     = NULLIF( Util.Trim(@StreetType     ), '');
    SET @StreetPostDir  = NULLIF( Util.Trim(@StreetPostDir  ), '');

    DECLARE @Result VarChar(100) =  @StreetNumber;

    IF @StreetDir IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        IF @Result IS NOT NULL
            SET @Result = @Result + ' ' + @StreetDir;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = @StreetDir;
    END

    IF @StreetName IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        IF @Result IS NOT NULL
            SET @Result = @Result + ' ' + @StreetName;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = @StreetName;
    END


    IF @StreetType IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        IF @Result IS NOT NULL
            SET @Result = @Result + ' ' + @StreetType;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = @StreetType;
    END

    IF @StreetPostDir IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        IF @Result IS NOT NULL
            SET @Result = @Result + ' ' + @StreetPostDir;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = @StreetPostDir;
    END

    RETURN NULLIF(@Result, '');
END

CREATE FUNCTION [Util].[Trim]
(
    @value nVarChar(max)
)
RETURNS nVarChar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN LTrim(RTrim(@value))
END
```

Comment: What is the smallest dervied function that SQL Server says is ND from that? (That is, this does not appear to be a minimal test-case.)

Comment: @ypercube Yea, that's just a typo. I know better.

Comment: @billinkc No, it's just a wrapper around LTrim(RTim(value)). If you scroll down you can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You could create both function `WITH SCHEMABINDING`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.[Trim]
(
    @value nVarChar(max)
)
RETURNS nVarChar(max)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
...
```

and

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.[BuildStreetFullName]
(
    @StreetNumber VARCHAR(20),
    @StreetDir VARCHAR(2),
    @StreetName VARCHAR(50) ,
    @StreetType VARCHAR(4) ,
    @StreetPostDir VARCHAR(2) 
)
RETURNS VarChar(100)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
...
```

This will force SQL Server to check if these function are deterministic or not.

```
SELECT  OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.[BuildStreetFullName]') , 'IsDeterministic' ) AS IsDeterministic
```

Output:

```
IsDeterministic
---------------
1
```

2) Please don't use `!= NULL`  operator to check for `NOT NULL`. Use `IS NOT NULL`. At this moment `ANSI_NULLS OFF` is deprecated and a a future version of SQL Server will allow only `ANSI_NULLS ON`.

3) Scalar functions can be a nightmare from performance point of view. I would **rewrite** those functions as [inline table valued functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't see anything in the documentation to support that, but it works.

Comment: Point three has become slightly *lost in translation*.  I think you're proposing `scalar multi-statement` => `table-valued inline`.

Comment: Regarding inline functions, I tested them in SQL Server 2014 using Util.Trim as a base case. According to the query execution plan, there is no cost difference. Perhaps using INLINE is no longer a performance concern for scalar functions.

Comment: @MatBailie: Thanks for clarification. yes. The proposal is to rewrite those functions as INLINE table valued functions. SQL Server has only one type of INLINE user defined functions: table valued functions.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: The execution plans are not the everything. There are performance problems which can't be detected by analyzing the execution plans (ex. memory pressure). In this case I would compare `CPU` time and `Duration` using a trace (ex. SQL Profiler) or using a XE session.

Comment: Agree with @MatBailie that the phrasing in #3 sounds a little odd. It is true that inline functions in SQL Server can only be table-valued (at least so far), yet technically the term is not just *inline function* but *inline table-valued function*. By leaving out *table-valued* you seem to be contrasting just *scalar* with *inline*, which makes little sense. I believe you should spell out *table-valued*, because switching to those would affect your queries.